# decode Persian characters on android

Tags: php, android, decode

i get some characters(English and Persian) of php and decode on android,i use of utf-8 format,but on the output show question mark characters.
this my code:

```
    try {    
        JSONObject toSend = new JSONObject();
        toSend.put("type", "all");

       String result="";   
        JSONTransmitter transmitter = new JSONTransmitter();
      AsyncTask<JSONObject, JSONObject, JSONObject> jo=  transmitter.execute(new JSONObject[] {toSend});
     JSONObject jjjj=jo.get();

    JSONArray array=jjjj.getJSONArray("rows");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length()-1; i++) {
        JSONObject json_data = array.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONArray arr1=json_data.getJSONArray("row");
        str_url[i]=arr1.getString(0);   
        str_id[i]= URLDecoder.decode(arr1.getString(1), "UTF-8");


        Log.d("GEEEETTTT BYYYYTTTEEE", str_id[i] );
        Log.d("GEEEETTTT BYYYYTTTEEE",str_id[i]);

    }     

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSONException****:::", e.getMessage());      


    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e("InterruptedException:::", e.getMessage());
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        Log.e("ExecutionException:::", e.getMessage());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e("UnsupportedEncodingException:::", e.getMessage());
    }
```

and this my Log cat:
[image: Log]

Comment: 1. do not use `AsyncTask<>.get()` 2. you are decoding too late ... 3. you did not show us JSONTransmitter code, and the error is there ...

Answer (score 0):

this is my JSONTransmitter:

```
public class JSONTransmitter extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, JSONObject, JSONObject> {
String url = "my url";

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... data) {
    JSONObject json = data[0];
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 100000);

    JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    try {
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity("json="+json.toString());
        post.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        post.setEntity(se);

        HttpResponse response;
        response = client.execute(post);
        String resFromServer = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        jsonResponse=new JSONObject(resFromServer);

    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}

    return jsonResponse;
}
```

}

Comment: If you display resFromServer on a TextView, are the Persian characters there? Did you try EntityUtils.toString(..., "utf-8");?

Comment: thanks for your comment,my problem solved.i should use of mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8") on php.